# Remove empty elements from a string

Tags: c#

I used this Linq statement to remove blank values from a string array

```
string phone = dt.Rows[i]["TelStandard1"] + System.Environment.NewLine + dt.Rows[i]["TelStandard2"] + System.Environment.NewLine + dt.Rows[i]["TelStandard3"] + System.Environment.NewLine + dt.Rows[i]["TelStandard4"] + System.Environment.NewLine + dt.Rows[i]["TelStandard5"];
phone = phone.Where( x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
```

But i got this error message

> Error 2   The best overloaded method match for 'string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)' has some invalid arguments

How to fix this error?

Comment: I wonder if you pretended to do `phone.Split(Environment.NewLine).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray()`

Comment: @baileyrt What? No, the error message makes perfect sense because `phone` is a `string` and there is nothing in the code that attempts to set it to an array

Comment: *"remove blank values from a string array"* - Perhaps your terminology is getting mixed up here.  You have a string.  What specifically are you trying to do with that string?

Comment: a ``string`` does not contain (blank) "elements".

Comment: dt.Rows[i]["TelStandard1"] may contains null values i want to remove them

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `phone` is a `string`, so, in your LINQ, `x` is a `char` and `string.IsNullOrEmpty` takes a `string`.

I would do something like this instead:

```
string phone = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    // create an array with all possible values
    new string[]
    {
        dt.Rows[i]["TelStandard1"],
        dt.Rows[i]["TelStandard2"],
        dt.Rows[i]["TelStandard3"],
        dt.Rows[i]["TelStandard4"],
        dt.Rows[i]["TelStandard5"]
    }
    // then filter those that are empty
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the where statement you get char each time.
I suggest you to use this linq statement:

```
String output = String.Concat(str.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
```